# Is there anyway to get full rendered HTML code of any website (with JavaScript code included)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

Is there any way we get the full HTML source code of a website with JavaScript code (fetched from 3rd party) are also included in it?

I understand we can get using `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` but it will not include the 3rd party JS in the HTML code?

[image]

The reason for this question (based on my knowledge) is when the browser renders and create DOM then it should have all the required files so does anyone know where and how we can get that full HTML source code of any website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes when the browser renders the page it does indeed fetch these resources, you can use the save option provided by the browser, by clicking right click, then save as, then save as a complete webpage.

If the previous does not work, then there are many tools, extensions, applications that provides this functionality and its easy to search for them.

If you want to save the html and its resources in one html file, you can save it as mhtml file, using this extension for example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-webpages-offline-as/nfbcfginnecenjncdjhaminfcienmehn.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Every time I've saved a page in *any* browser, it creates a folder with *all* of the linked files - for js files, it usually adds `.download` after the extension.

Comment: @ATD no i'm not sure thats why i said as far as i can tell, btw i tried now, and indeed chrome on my system has added download as a complete webpage option, where resources are also downloaded, this is something that did not appear for me before, idk when this was added.
Thanks a lot for letting me know, i edited my answer

Comment: I think that this is something that has been there for years.  I have copies of pages dated over 10 years ago that included all related items in sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But my question is to more about an automatic process (rather than manual) like some kind of method of API (which browser provides like document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML) which I call and it should print the entire HTML in console (just an e.g.)